# Haskell colon and dot syntax?

Tags: haskell

I've run into the following code on a project I viewed on Github:

```
data LispVal = Atom String
             | Number Integer
             | String String
             | Bool Bool
             | LispVal :. LispVal -- Cons
```

What exactly does the `:.` syntax signifiy? I've never seen it before?

Comment: You ahev probably seen `x:xs` to construct lists. Similarly, `:.` constructs `LispVal`.

Comment: "Strange symbols" are almost never actually _special syntax_ in Haskell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:.` is just a data constructor that has been defined. You can play in ghci to get an idea:

```
*Main> let a = Atom "test1"
*Main> let b = Atom "test2"
*Main> let c = a :. b
*Main> c
Atom "test1" :. Atom "test2"
```

I have added `deriving (Show)` in your code so that it shows us String in the REPL. You can also see it's type:

```
*Main> :t (:.)
(:.) :: LispVal -> LispVal -> LispVal
```

So, in effect it's just a function which takes two `LispVal` values and returns a value of `LispVal` type.

Comment: It's a *data constructor*, not quite a "normal" function.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, "normal" variables begin with a lowercase letter, and constructor names begin with an uppercase letter. That's how the compiler can tell them apart.

Haskell also allows you to *define* brand-new operators. For example, you could create a new operator called `?+?` which produces a string telling you what it did:

```
x ?+? y = show x ++ " + " ++ show y ++ " = " ++ show (x + y)
```

So far, so good.

Haskell *also* allows a constructor to be an operator. For "normal" names, if the first letter is lowercase, it's a normal variable, and if it's uppercase it's a constructor. For *operators*, if the first character is `:` then it's a constructor, otherwise it's a "normal" operator.

You've probably seen the list type, which has two constructors, `[]` (which is magic) and `:`. Obviously, the operator `:` "begins with" `:`. But you can invent new ones yourself:

```
data Foobar = Int :?? String deriving Show

test = 5 :?? "banana"
```

Just so long as the operator starts with `:`, it can appear in a `data` declaration.